# Как удалить определенный тип данных из списка?

Tags: python, list

Дан список:

```
a = [0,5,4,546,43,5365,64,6,756,'hi','ju']
```

Как из этого списка удалить, к примеру, только строковые данные `'hi'`, `'ju'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверить тип можно функцией [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type), а дальше, либо удалить элементы неподходящего типа в цикле, либо сформировать новый список с помощью генератора, проверяя некоторое условие.

***Пример:***

```py
a = [0, 5, 4, 546, 43, 5365, 64, 6, 756, 'hi', 'ju']

result = [x for x in a if type(x) != str]
print(result)  # [0, 5, 4, 546, 43, 5365, 64, 6, 756]
```

Comment: А я больше через `isinstance` люблю ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [0, 5, 4, 546, 43, 5365, 64, 6, 756, 'hi', 'ju']
result = list(filter(lambda el: not isinstance(el, str), a))
```

```
a = [0, 5, 4, 546, 43, 5365, 64, 6, 756, 'hi', 'ju']
result = [i for i in a if not isinstance(i, str)]
```

Comment: Замечу, что `isinstance(i, int)` удалит также элементы типа `bool`, проверив наследование. Поэтому это нельзя считать проверкой на **тип**.

Comment: @nomnoms12 ага, ты прав.